# Meteor - encrypt service accessToken

Tags: meteor, encryption

I tried to use https://docs.meteor.com/packages/oauth-encryption.html to encrypt service.accessToken but it seems that it does not work.

I added following code into my accounts.js file in Meteor application:

```
Accounts.config({ oauthSecretKey: 'secretk_key' });
```

When I create an user and check in MongoDB  this token is not encrypted.

Comment: Please read the oauth package [documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/oauth-encryption.html). It introduces methods to encrypt your token.

Comment: Yeah, I read that documentation. I tested it, but it does not work. My accessToken in MongoDB is not encrypted.